# DownloadStringAsync doesn't return complete string

Tags: c#, downloadstring

I download a bunch of strings from different addresses and I need to download them as quick as possible. So I use 10 DownloadStringAsync and 1 DownloadString.

Simplified code looks like this:

```
    ...
    foreach(...)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            if (asyncworkers < 10)
            {
                client.DownloadStringCompleted += Done;
                client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
                asyncworkers++;
            }else{
                string data = client.DownloadString(uri);
                ProcessData(data);
            }
        }
    }
    ...


private void Done(...)
{
    ProcessData(e.Result);
    asyncworkers--;
}
```

The issue is that from time to time `e.Result` in `Done` is not complete. When I use either only `DownloadString` or `DownloadStringAsync` then it is most likely allways complete.
Is it normal and shall I just redownload it when it isn't complete or is the way I wrote it wrong? And in case it is wrong how would I force it to wait untill one of 10 `DownloadStringAsync` finishes its work?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the same client multiple times concurrently? If so, that's probably the issue.

Comment: No. I edited the sample code. Each loop has its own client.

Comment: Now you've edited the code, it looks like you're disposing of the `WebClient` immediately - before it's actually finished processing. That's quite possibly the problem now.

Comment: You mean `Done` is called when `WebClient` that called it no longer exists? When shall I dispose it?

Comment: It exists as an object, but you've disposed it. You should only dispose it when the callback occurs. Note that if you're using .NET 4.5, using async/await makes all of this a lot simpler.

Comment: Could you more specify or forward me somewhere where it is explained. I have tried to create `WebClient` just once and then under `foreach` use the one creared above. But it throws an arror.

Comment: No, I certainly wasn't suggesting that - that would be a bad idea. I'm suggesting that you should only dispose of the `WebClient` when you've actually finished with it. For the sync version, that's as soon as `DownloadString` has finished. For the async version, it's when the appropriate event handler (possibly the error handler) has fired.